# Angular interpolate scope variable in ng-click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

How do I construct the name of a scope variable in ng-click.
E.g the I have a form in ng-repeat where the name is generated dynamically.
I am using x-editable plugin so name in this case will create a scope variable called {{box.key}}{{$index}}

```
<div ng-repeat="course in box.value track by $index">    
 <form editable-form name="{{box.key}}{{$index}}">
```

The question is how to access the variable dynamically. The button is also in the ng-repeate div.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="{{box.key}}{{$index}}.$show()">Edit</button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your forms are declared inside ng-repeat, which defines one child scope per repeated div. So, to make sure the forms are accessible from the controler scope and not only from the child ng-repeat scope, make sure your controller defines an empty object (or array) of forms:

```
$scope.forms = {};
```

and that the generated name of the forms looks like `forms.form1`. For example:

```
<form editable-form name="forms.{{box.key}}{{$index}}">
```

Then in your view:

```
ng-click="showForm(box.key, $index)"
```

and in your controller:

```
$scope.showForm = function(key, index) {
    var formName = key + index
    $scope.forms[formName].$show();
}
```

Comment: This seems like it would work but I am still having issues, I am getting TypeError: Cannot read property '$show' of undefined when running ng-click="showForm(box.key, $index)" and when I console.log($scope)  I can't find the formname as a $scope variable, yet hard coding it e.g. formname.$show() works

Comment: That's because your forms are declared inside ng-repeat, which defines one child scope per repeated div. Make sure your controller defines an empty object or array) of forms (`$scope.forms = {};`), and that the generated name of the forms looks like `forms.form1`.

Comment: But then my original answer won't work, so I'll edit it.

Comment: Thanks to @JBNizet I got this working in a JSFiddle, at jsfiddle.net/xpmLgL69/14 for reference.